# force app to ignore local assemblies and use SxS or vice versa

Tags: c#, .net, dll, manifest, winsxs

I have an application that is deployed in 2 flavors, with a WiX installer in person by an administrator, or with a click-once installer by a user with no elevated privileges.  It has a dependency on a set of 3rd party dlls which are designed to be deployed in an SxS manner.  However due to the need for elevated privileges to install to winSxS the click-once install needs to install the files locally to the bin directory of the application.  This is possible in the WiX install also, and causes no problems, however there is a problem...

Other 3rd (or 4th) party applications using the same set of dlls install them into winSxS, and when our application loads it accesses both the local version and the version in winSxS.  This causes some strange UI corruption with respect to resources loaded from an unmanaged resource dll by the SxS dlls.

To complicate matters all the dlls in the shared SxS set from the 3rd party have a manifest embedded that specifies a dependency on the SxS set directly.

I have tried adding to the application manifest the dependency on the SxS set but the problem persists that both versions are accessed:

```
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="sharedSXS" version="12.1.369.0" publicKeyToken="1255b113b2b03444" type="win32"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

but top no avail.

My question is this:

Is there a way to continue the application running successfully if no other applications are installed on the machine and the dlls are in the application bin directory, whilst also running successfully if another application installs the dlls into winSxS.
In other words, can I force the application to load exclusively from winSxS or locally which ever is present in both scenarios where the dlls exist in winSxS or not.

**Extra Info**

The application accesses the dll using a dllImport:

```
[DllImport("ExternalDll.dll", EntryPoint = "_DoStuff@12")]
[CLSCompliantAttribute(false)]
public static extern IntPtr DoStuffEx(string name, string reserved, uint uiFlags);
```

and the dll has the embedded manifest:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity name="ExternalDLL.dll" processorArchitecture="x86" type="win32" version="12.0.0.0"></assemblyIdentity>
 <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="sharedSXS" version="12.1.369.0" publicKeyToken="1255b113b2b03444" type="win32"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
</assembly>
```

and the SxS Manifest looks like follows:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="sharedSXS" version="12.1.369.0" publicKeyToken="1255b113b2b03444"></assemblyIdentity>
<file name="ExternalDLL.dll" hashalg="SHA1" hash="cb2ecfaca2d62cd9f5c559cf21d502921881155f"><asmv2:hash xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><dsig:Transforms><dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity"></dsig:Transform></dsig:Transforms><dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></dsig:DigestMethod><dsig:DigestValue>BLyJ40vJD++ih9XTg0oOcZhISl4=</dsig:DigestValue></asmv2:hash></file>
<file name="OtherDLL.dll" hashalg="SHA1" hash="246d082823724f42d5630dba1b9dcde3e2c1b76d"><asmv2:hash xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><dsig:Transforms><dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity"></dsig:Transform></dsig:Transforms><dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></dsig:DigestMethod><dsig:DigestValue>me1EL8p76nkfD1o9L058m8GUdaw=</dsig:DigestValue></asmv2:hash></file>
</assembly>
```

there are 4 scenarios:

1. application has no manifest, SxS not installed -> app loads dll locally if present else fails
2. application has manifest, SxS not installed -> app loads dll locally if present else fails
3. application has no manifest, SxS present ->

   A. app loads dll locally if present, dll then loads dependency from SxS corruption occurs

   B. no local dll, app fails
4. application has manifest, SxS present ->

   A. app loads dll locally if present, dll then loads dependency from SxS corruption occurs

   B. no local dll, app loads from SxS all is well

There are 2 scenarios I need to make work:

1. dll in local folder only (none in SxS)
2. dll in local folder and SxS

I have total control over the application manifest and the dllImport so any modification needed here are under my control. The scenario with the dlls in SxS only is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

How do you install local assemblies? Did you try installing them in assembly name folder?

```
yourapp.exe
sharedSXS/ExternalDLL.dll
sharedSXS/sharedSXS.manifest
sharedSXS/OtherDLL.dll
```

Then apps without manifest will not find dlls at all, and apps with manifest will prefer global copy before local copy, never using both.